# Android exception with setting text color on bottom navigation view

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have an Android application, written using Xamarin.Android but I believe the issue applies Android in general. I have the app installed on a few test devices and it was working fine at first. However, at some point the app started crashing constantly. I don't know how it got in this state but from that point forward, it happens constantly. Because it is already installed, all I could do was use LogCat to look at the error. I cannot use the Visual Studio debugger because it essentially re-installs the app and the error does not happen. I have been trying for a while with the app in debug mode to get it to go back in this state but I have been unsuccessful so far.

I feel like I need the debugger to give me a bit more information to figure this out. I am pretty sure, based on the errors below that the issue is the bottom navigation is null and that is why it cannot set the text. However, I am not sure how the bottom navigation can be null, how we get in this state and why a restart does not fix it, only a re-install does.

Here is the error I see in LogCat:

[image: LogCat Error]

Here is the axml where I have the bottom navigation view and where it sets the text color:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:elevation="16dp"
        android:background="@color/backgroundNormal"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/lightText"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/lightText"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation" />
```

And this is the bottom_navigation xml from the menu folder:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

   <!--Update strings and icons-->
   <item android:id="@+id/menu_batches"
      android:title="Batches"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_arrow_back"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

   <item android:id="@+id/menu_options"
     android:title="Options"
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_options"
     app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

   <item android:id="@+id/menu_home"
     android:title="Home"
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_home"
     app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

   <item android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
     android:title="Settings"
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
     app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

   <item android:id="@+id/menu_post"
     android:title="Post"
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_arrow_forward"
     app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

Any ideas on how I can debug or troubleshoot this further or does anybody have a better idea from the LogCat log on what might be happening and how I can fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Using your code, I cannot reproduce your issue. It worked all right. So the problem is somewhere else. Maybe you can post your full code so that it would be more easier to figure it out.

Comment: try deleting obj bin or clean the project

Comment: @AbbyWang Thank you for the response and trying this. I agree, the issue is not happening during Debug. I just found out it only happens on Release mode and it happens consistently on Release. However, with this clue, I still haven't figured out how to fix it. I Changed Linking to SDK only and also tried None (which is what it is set to during debug) and it still happens. The only difference in Android Options now is Use Shared Runtime. Unless the issue is with the code in general in Release.

Comment: Glad you solved it. I suggest you mark your answer so that when others account with similar problem, it is easier for them to find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I found the answer. After a frustrating amount of time lost, searching, testing, etc...

I knew the clue based on the errors was that it had something to do with the bottom navigation bar. I also found out that it only happens in release mode and not in debug mode. The first obvious thing to do was change the release configuration settings (changed linking options, etc...) but none of those fixed it.

So, I did more research and found that the bottom navigation bar relies on the Xamarin.Android.Support library and that it must be v25 or greater. I had satisfied this requirement so this wasn't my issue either.

However, I found that I should also have the Xamarin.Android.Support.Transition library too. I noticed that this was not in my references so I added it via NuGet and guess what...problem fixed. Just like that, something so simple but not obvious with initial tests and errors. So, I hope this helps somebody. Not sure why it was not included when I added the support library reference a while back, I would think it would be a required reference that is automatically added too. Also, why this would cause it to fail in release and not in debug, I will never know!!!